# link in message body of email is not working

Tags: android, html, email

I need to send email with attached image and message body contain two
       links.Everything is working fine except link is not working but it's 
       text is showing.I tried by add two link to message body  by single
       putExtra method.

```
 Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 

    emailIntent.setType("text/html");
    emailIntent.setType("application/octet-stream");  
    emailIntent.setType("image/jpeg");



    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, 
        "A post card from \"I'm in!\" xyz"); 


    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,     Uri.parse("file://"+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+"tempImage.jpg"));

        String temp="Find out more about <a href=\"http://www.xyz.com\"> Greeting Card application</a><br>";

        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml("Please&nbsp;visit us at <a href=\"http://www.xyz.com\">www.xyz.com</a>.")); 
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(temp)); 
        temp="Please visit us at <a href=\"http://www.jxyz.com\"> www.xyz.com <http://www.xyz.com> </a></br>FInd out more about <a href=\"http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app56769?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D2\">I'm In! - Greeting Card</a> application";
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(temp)); 
        startActivityForResult((Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail...")),mailSendCode);
```

Thanks,
Kariyachan

Answer (score 0):

You can try just put this link into

```
emailIntent.setType("text/html");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, temp);
```

Comment: Anyone able to found a solution for the same? The links work fine in Gmail but not in native email clients or outlook.